# multiple lines in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I found this function for ROC calculation

```
  getROC_AUC = function(probs, true_Y){
    probsSort = sort(probs, decreasing = TRUE, index.return = TRUE)
    val = unlist(probsSort$x)
    idx = unlist(probsSort$ix)  

    roc_y = true_Y[idx];
    stack_x = cumsum(roc_y == 0)/sum(roc_y == 0)
    stack_y = cumsum(roc_y == 1)/sum(roc_y == 1)    

    auc = sum((stack_x[2:length(roc_y)]-stack_x[1:length(roc_y)-1])*stack_y[2:length(roc_y)])
    return(list(stack_x=stack_x, stack_y=stack_y, auc=auc))
  }
```

I am trying to use this function to draw ROC curve for different models in the same plot.

I store the target variable and the probabilities for the different models in a data.frame

temp:

```
    target Model.L Model.R Model.N Model.Comb
  1        0   0.150   0.400   0.125      0.225
  2        0   0.195   0.610   0.141      0.315
  3        1   0.315   0.455   0.646      0.472
  4        0   0.100   0.195   0.053      0.116
  5        0   0.635   0.394   0.565      0.531
  6        0   0.172   0.394   0.149      0.238
  7        0   0.090   0.195   0.075      0.120
  8        1   0.188   0.222   0.282      0.231
  9        0   0.582   0.333   0.743      0.553
  10       0   0.201   0.195   0.084      0.160
  11       0   0.166   0.394   0.115      0.225
  12       1   0.422   0.688   0.623      0.578
  13       0   0.173   0.688   0.361      0.407
  14       0   0.239   0.333   0.212      0.261
  15       0   0.094   0.636   0.123      0.284
  16       1   0.869   0.579   0.778      0.742
  17       0   0.350   0.195   0.314      0.286
  18       0   0.102   0.195   0.153      0.150
  19       0   0.216   0.394   0.211      0.274
  20       1   0.097   0.727   0.180      0.335
  21       0   0.306   0.195   0.147      0.216
  22       0   0.081   0.562   0.188      0.277
  23       0   0.102   0.195   0.085      0.127
  24       0   0.118   0.195   0.071      0.128
  25       1   0.702   0.394   0.587      0.561
  26       1   0.520   0.769   0.774      0.688
  27       0   0.485   0.769   0.625      0.626
  28       0   0.093   0.688   0.110      0.297
  29       0   0.198   0.562   0.405      0.388
  30       0   0.039   0.195   0.019      0.084
  31       0   0.387   0.195   0.250      0.277
  32       0   0.283   0.195   0.209      0.229
  33       1   0.461   0.455   0.720      0.545
  34       0   0.365   0.195   0.251      0.270
  35       0   0.059   0.195   0.041      0.098
  36       0   0.063   0.195   0.030      0.096
  37       0   0.210   0.195   0.099      0.168
  38       0   0.285   0.195   0.192      0.224
  39       0   0.161   0.610   0.174      0.315
  40       0   0.307   0.195   0.306      0.269
  41       0   0.477   0.195   0.458      0.377
  42       0   0.231   0.394   0.311      0.312
  43       0   0.123   0.610   0.148      0.294
  44       0   0.100   0.195   0.203      0.166
  45       1   0.453   0.195   0.336      0.328
  46       0   0.188   0.727   0.153      0.356
  47       0   0.020   0.394   0.025      0.146
  48       0   0.477   0.195   0.419      0.364
  49       1   0.497   0.610   0.566      0.558
  50       1   0.302   0.857   0.515      0.558
  51       1   0.407   0.195   0.372      0.325
  52       1   0.171   0.222   0.490      0.294
  53       0   0.194   0.195   0.098      0.162
  54       0   0.131   0.394   0.085      0.203
  55       1   0.875   0.286   0.875      0.679
  56       1   0.939   0.769   0.986      0.898
  57       0   0.448   0.394   0.328      0.390
  58       0   0.729   0.333   0.735      0.599
  59       0   0.827   0.286   0.863      0.659
  60       0   0.225   0.195   0.098      0.173
  61       0   0.114   0.195   0.106      0.138
  62       0   0.218   0.394   0.150      0.254
  63       0   0.112   0.195   0.076      0.128
  64       0   0.163   0.394   0.147      0.235
  65       0   0.250   0.286   0.227      0.254
  66       0   0.258   0.394   0.166      0.273
  67       0   0.194   0.562   0.362      0.373
  68       0   0.459   0.400   0.563      0.474
  69       0   0.103   0.579   0.142      0.275
  70       1   0.408   0.769   0.525      0.567
  71       1   0.469   0.394   0.423      0.429
  72       0   0.187   0.195   0.127      0.170
  73       0   0.129   0.610   0.166      0.302
  74       0   0.148   0.195   0.122      0.155
  75       0   0.107   0.195   0.121      0.141
  76       0   0.281   0.195   0.175      0.217
  77       0   0.148   0.727   0.182      0.352
  78       0   0.621   0.286   0.602      0.503
  79       1   0.382   0.610   0.277      0.423
  80       0   0.098   0.333   0.106      0.179
  81       0   0.247   0.195   0.096      0.179
  82       0   0.223   0.195   0.168      0.195
  83       0   0.214   0.195   0.129      0.179
  84       0   0.497   0.195   0.455      0.382
  85       0   0.388   0.195   0.299      0.294
  86       0   0.140   0.579   0.307      0.342
  87       1   0.530   0.195   0.491      0.405
  88       0   0.346   0.579   0.403      0.443
  89       1   0.338   0.562   0.618      0.506
  90       1   0.782   0.195   0.553      0.510
  91       0   0.155   0.195   0.115      0.155
  92       0   0.245   0.562   0.504      0.437
  93       0   0.290   0.400   0.361      0.350
  94       1   0.303   0.769   0.576      0.549
  95       0   0.076   0.195   0.052      0.108
  96       1   0.595   0.688   0.650      0.644
  97       0   0.122   0.394   0.103      0.206
  98       1   0.814   0.769   0.942      0.842
  99       0   0.034   0.195   0.019      0.083
  100      1   0.261   0.455   0.553      0.423
  101      0   0.403   0.195   0.214      0.271
  102      1   0.484   0.455   0.548      0.496
  103      0   0.083   0.195   0.068      0.115
  104      0   0.386   0.125   0.503      0.338
  105      1   0.860   0.195   0.788      0.614
  106      0   0.172   0.727   0.190      0.363
  107      0   0.099   0.195   0.116      0.137
  108      1   0.840   0.636   0.767      0.748
  109      0   0.136   0.195   0.126      0.152
  110      0   0.174   0.195   0.087      0.152
  111      0   0.092   0.394   0.065      0.184
  112      0   0.288   0.394   0.143      0.275
  113      1   0.661   0.769   0.860      0.763
  114      1   0.791   0.579   0.745      0.705
  115      0   0.439   0.195   0.347      0.327
  116      1   0.902   0.195   0.930      0.676
  117      0   0.058   0.195   0.041      0.098
  118      0   0.780   0.195   0.609      0.528
  119      0   0.154   0.195   0.074      0.141
  120      0   0.211   0.195   0.161      0.189
  121      1   0.797   0.579   0.850      0.742
  122      1   0.830   0.333   0.900      0.688
  123      0   0.227   0.195   0.290      0.237
```

Thats my code:

```
aList<-getROC_AUC(temp[,Names[1]],temp[,"target"])
        stack_x = unlist(aList$stack_x)
        stack_y = unlist(aList$stack_y)
        temp.data<-data.frame(stack_x,stack_y)
        p<-ggplot(temp.data,aes(x=stack_x,y=stack_y))+geom_line(aes(colour=Names[1]))+
          labs(x="probability of false alarm", sub = "(1-Specificity)",y="probability of detection\n(Sensitivity)")


        for(i in Names[-1]){
          aList<-getROC_AUC(temp[,i],temp[,"target"])
          stack_x = unlist(aList$stack_x)
          stack_y = unlist(aList$stack_y)
          temp.data<-data.frame(stack_x,stack_y)
          p<-p+geom_line(data=temp.data,aes(x=stack_x,y=stack_y,colour=i))
        }
        p
```

And thats the plot which i am getting:
[image]

How can i get different colour per model?

Thanks

Comment: how is your question related to shiny?

Comment: `ggplot` does weird things when you try to assemble layers in a loop. The way you're intended to use `ggplot` is to assemble your data into a single data frame and then color based on a `model_id` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Consider base R's `reshape`, `by`, and `do.call` to transform your dataframe into long format for a grouped calculation to build a singular master long dataframe. As the rule of thumb, `ggplot` (and any other data analysis needs) always works best with long data.

Your function will then have to be adjusted to receive and return a dataframe as input parameter for `by` call wrapped in `do.call(rbind, ...)` for final dataframe build. Finally pass the master long dataframe into your plotting for one call without any loops using *colour* set to *Model* variable.

```
long_df <- reshape(temp, varying = names(temp)[-1], direction = "long",
                   timevar = "name", new.row.names = 1:10000)

# ADJUSTED FUNCTION
getROC_AUC <- function(df){
  probsSort <- sort(df$Model, decreasing = TRUE, index.return = TRUE)
  val <- unlist(probsSort$x)
  idx <- unlist(probsSort$ix)  

  roc_y <- df$target[idx];
  stack_x <- cumsum(roc_y == 0)/sum(roc_y == 0)
  stack_y <- cumsum(roc_y == 1)/sum(roc_y == 1)    

  auc <- sum((stack_x[2:length(roc_y)]-stack_x[1:length(roc_y)-1])
              *stack_y[2:length(roc_y)])

  df <- data.frame(Model=max(df$name), stack_x, stack_y)

  return(df)
}

# STACK ALL GROUPED DATAFRAMES
model_df <- do.call(rbind, unname(by(long_df, long_df$name, getROC_AUC)))

p <- ggplot(model_df, aes(x=stack_x, y=stack_y, colour=Model)) + geom_line() +
  labs(x = "probability of false alarm", sub = "(1-Specificity)",
       y = "probability of detection\n(Sensitivity)")

p
```

[image: Plot Output]